# improve mysql select query speed

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu-12.04

I am using `mysql 14.14` in my `django` application.

One of my tables has **300,000+** records having 30 columns.

On page load i have to list all the date field values.

So I queried with 'Select date from table'. But it takes about **35 seconds** to load the page.

How can I improve the speed of the query ?

*I am working in Ubuntu 12.04 i3 processor 4GB RAM 320GB hardisk.*

Comment: Do you have an index on that date column?

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is your database? Rendering the template and transferring the data to your browser is bound to take some time.

Comment: And also browser rendering that many elements.

Comment: Now I checked if the issue is with the database by running the same query in the database. It took only 3 seconds!!!. So it is with the django code that this slowness is happening. I am using class-based view. How will I speed up the process? Aritra, how will I check if a field is indexed?

Comment: @user12757 Depends on what you're doing to the data in your view. Althought my bet is on browser. Browser can take a lot of time rendering that many elements. Have you considered paginating?

Comment: This issue arised in firefox latest version. I also tried it in latest chrome. There also the issue persists. In my application I am using jqxgrid with pagination, 1000 rows per page. This data is taken from the database using class view.

Comment: I checked the django orm query in the shell and checked the speed, it takes only 0.163secs!!!.

Comment: Actually when I printed the query output using for loop, it took more than 16secs. I am just selecting one field from the model. Is it posible to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

Indexes should be enough to optimize your query. Have a look at this docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)